# Select rows in a R dataframe by multiple conditions (find genes with differential expression in multiple comparisons)

Tags: r, dataframe

After differential expression analysis, we have a data frame with genes, 4 different comparison groups, and the respective logFC (Foldchange) and FDR (false discovery rate) values.

We want to find the genes, that show defined values in each of the comparison groups (eg. all genes with a logFC > 2 and an FDR < 0.05 in every comparison).

Example data:

```
gene_creator <- paste("gene",1:1000,sep="")
genes = sample(gene_creator,100)

dex_A <- data.frame(
  gene = genes,
  group = "group_A",
  logFC = sample(c(-5:5), replace=T, size=100),
  FDR = sample(c(0.01,1), replace=T, size=100)
)

dex_B <- data.frame(
  gene = genes,
  group = "group_B",
  logFC = sample(c(-5:5), replace=T, size=100),
  FDR = sample(c(0.01,1), replace=T, size=100)
)

dex_C <- data.frame(
  gene = genes,
  group = "group_C",
  logFC = sample(c(-5:5), replace=T, size=100),
  FDR = sample(c(0.01,1), replace=T, size=100)
)

dex_D <- data.frame(
  gene = genes,
  group = "group_D",
  logFC = sample(c(-5:5), replace=T, size=100),
  FDR = sample(c(0.01,1), replace=T, size=100)
)


dex_df <- rbind(dex_A, dex_B, dex_C, dex_D)
```

Expected output:

A vector with each gene where Fc > 2 and FDR < 0.05 in each of the comparison groups. If a gene does not show the criteria in one group, it should not be in the vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With dplyr (v1.1.0 or higher), `filter()` grouped `.by` `gene`, keeping rows where criteria are met in `all()` groups. Then `pull()` `unique()` `gene`s into a vector.

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(195)

dex_df %>% 
  filter(all(logFC > 2 & FDR < .05), .by = gene) %>% 
  pull(gene) %>% 
  unique()
# "gene26"  "gene715"
```

Or a base R split-apply approach:

```
dex_df_all_4 <- dex_df |>
  split(f = dex_df$gene) |>
  sapply(\(x) all(x$logFC > 2 & x$FDR < .05))

names(dex_df_all_4[dex_df_all_4])
# "gene26"  "gene715"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick answer! After reviewing the data, it seems too strikt to ask for all comparisons to adhere to the criteria. Is there a way to say, eg at least two of the comparisons have to adhere to it (and two dont)? Many thanks!

Comment: Sure, replace the condition with `sum(logFC > 2 & FDR < .05) >= 2`.